# Eclipse Java "pop-up" functions

Tags: java, eclipse

I have seen people on YouTube programming Java with the Eclipse editor, and they have a pop up that tells them all acceptable ways to finish your function.

i.e. if you type System.out., it will show a list of every possible thing you could write after System.out, such as print, println, etc.

Please tell me how to enable this feature.

Comment: I think it is called _Eclipse autocomplete_.

Comment: Hit `ctrl+space`. Go to `Window->Preferences->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced`

Comment: @francis:  You should consider adding that in as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its in the option its called auto completion/content assist.
menu -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content assist

also try using ctrl+space to complete when typing

Comment: the pop up appears when you start writing something and then you press ctrl+spacebar  ;there are different thing so pressing it a few time in a row will show different stuff/option.